# C# winforms Graphics oversize

Tags: c#, graphics2d

I have been trying for a week to draw an odd shape and then oversize it correctly by say .1 when I try with the code below I get this result:

[image: wrong result]

How can I "outline" the drawing with the correct aspect ratio?

Code:

```
            foreach (clsDisplayList p in mDisplayLists)
            {
                if (!p.InView)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (p.Rapid)
                {
                    mCurPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Custom;
                    mCurPen.DashPattern = mRapidDashStyle;
                }
                else
                {
                    mCurPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid;
                }
                path.AddLines(p.Points);
                mCurPen.Color = p.Color;
                g.DrawLines(mCurPen, p.Points);
            }

            g.ResetTransform();
            g.MultiplyTransform(mMtxDraw);
            g.TranslateTransform(0, 1);
            //make new matrix
            Matrix newpath = new Matrix();
            newpath.Translate(0, 1);
            newpath.Scale(1.1f, 1.1f);
            path.Transform(newpath);
            g.DrawPath(mCurPen, path); //tring to scale here
```

This code is based off of a project called cnc viewer.  I am basically trying to get my shape based off of gcode then oversize it so that I can modify my gcode for drill points.  I have written a program to write the gcode but have not figured out how to backblot it to allow a visual of the coordinates I need.  I have added the scaling code as requested.  The inside shape is correct, but I need the outside shape to be oversized by 2 inches.  I am drawing the "outside shape" after the initial shape is rendered. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17424/CNC-Graphical-Backplotter

```
    public void WindowViewport(float X1, float Y1, float X2, float Y2)
    {
        float temp = 0;

        //convert window from right to left
        if ((X1 > X2))
        {
            temp = X2;
            X2 = X1;
            X1 = temp;
        }

        //convert window from bottom to top
        if ((Y1 > Y2))
        {
            temp = Y2;
            Y2 = Y1;
            Y1 = temp;
        }

        if (Math.Abs(X2 - X1) < 0.01)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (Math.Abs(Y2 - Y1) > 1000)
        {
            return;
        }

        mViewRect.X = X1;
        mViewRect.Y = Y1;
        mViewRect.Width = X2 - X1;
        mViewRect.Height = Y2 - Y1;
        AdjustAspect();
    }

    private void SetBufferContext()
    {
        if (mGfxBuff != null)
        {
            mGfxBuff.Dispose();
            mGfxBuff = null;
        }
        // Retrieves the BufferedGraphicsContext for the
        // current application domain.
        mContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;

        // Sets the maximum size for the primary graphics buffer
        mContext.MaximumBuffer = new Size(this.Width + 1, this.Height + 1);

        // Allocates a graphics buffer the size of this control
        mGfxBuff = mContext.Allocate(CreateGraphics(), new Rectangle(0, 0, 
    this.Width, this.Height));
        mGfx = mGfxBuff.Graphics;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the matrix required to draw to the specified view
    /// </summary>
    private void SetViewMatrix()
    {
        if (float.IsInfinity(mViewRect.Width) | 
       float.IsInfinity(mViewRect.Height)) return;
        if (mViewRect.Width == 0 | mViewRect.Height == 0) return;

        //The ratio between the actual size of the screen and the size of the 
        graphics.
        mScaleToReal = (mClientRect.Width / mGfx.DpiX) / mViewRect.Width;
        if (first == 0)
        {
            mScale_stick = mScaleToReal;
            first = 1;
        }
        mMtxDraw.Reset();
        mMtxDraw.Scale(mScaleToReal, mScaleToReal);
        mMtxDraw.Translate(-mViewportCenter.X, mViewportCenter.Y);
        mMtxDraw.Translate((mViewRect.Width / 2f), (mViewRect.Height / 2f));
        mMtxDraw.Scale(1, -1);
        //Flip the Y

        //The matrix for the triad is the same as the other geometry but 
        without the scale
        mMtxWCS.Reset();
        mMtxWCS.Multiply(mMtxDraw);
        mMtxWCS.Scale(1 / mScaleToReal, 1 / mScaleToReal);

        mPixelF = ((1 / mGfx.DpiX) / mScaleToReal);
        mBlipSize = (mPixelF * 3f);

        SetFeedbackMatrix();
    }
```

Not sure if this would help but this is what I have tried to get the outside boarder to scale right:

```
 foreach (clsDisplayList p in mDisplayLists)
            {
                if (!p.InView)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (p.Rapid)
                {
                    mCurPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Custom;
                    mCurPen.DashPattern = mRapidDashStyle;
                }
                else
                {
                    mCurPen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Solid;
                }
                path.AddLines(p.Points);
                mCurPen.Color = p.Color;
                g.DrawLines(mCurPen, p.Points);
                LineFixUp(ref p.Points);

                foreach (PointF line in p.Points)
                {
                    if (Math.Abs(line.Y) > points)
                    {
                        points = Math.Abs(line.Y);
                    }
                    if (Math.Abs(line.X) > points)
                    {
                        pointsx = Math.Abs(line.X);
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        if (line.Y > 0)
                        {
                            useoffsettranslation = true;
                        }

                        if (line.Y < ytop)
                        {
                            points = line.Y;
                            ytop = line.Y;
                        }
                        if (line.Y > ybottom)
                        {
                            ybottom = line.Y;
                        }
                        if (line.X < xleft)
                        {
                            xleft = line.X;
                        }
                        if (line.X > xright)
                        {
                            xright = line.X;
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
            path.Flatten();
            mCurPen.Color = Color.Red;

            float third = 0;
            float fourth = 0;
            try
            {
                float first = Math.Abs(xleft) * 2;
                float second = (Math.Abs(xleft) * 2) + 2;
                third = (second / first);
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                float first = Math.Abs(ytop / 2) * 2;
                float second = (Math.Abs(ytop / 2) * 2) + 2; //trying to add 2 inches to oversize
                fourth = (second / first);
            }
            catch { }
            g.DrawPath(mCurPen, path);
            float tran = (points + 2) / points;
            tran = Math.Abs(aspect - tran) + tran;
            mCurPen.Color = Color.Pink;
            float off = fourth * .85f;
            Matrix translateMatrix = new Matrix();
            translateMatrix.Scale((float)third, (float)fourth);
            if (useoffsettranslation == false)// if G54 is not center
            {
                translateMatrix.Translate((float)0, off);
            }
            else
            {
                translateMatrix.Translate(0, 0);
            }
            g.DrawPath(mCurPen, path);
```

also the gcode for the file is:

G42
G01 Y-9.8484
G02 X-14.62 Y-7.8484 Z-0.0787 R2
G02 X-14.4063 Y-3.147 Z-0.0787 R51.8248
G02 X-11.441 Y-0.1132 Z-0.0787 R3.3602
G02 X-9.4488 Y0 Z-0.0787 R17.5728
G01 X5.9055
G02 X11.331 Y-0.1248 Z-0.0787 R117.9665
G02 X14.5344 Y-3.3534 Z-0.0787 R3.3603
G02 X14.6201 Y-7.8481 Z-0.0787 R117.9602
G02 X14.5332 Y-12.3735 Z-0.0787 R117.9602
G02 X9.9758 Y-17.7879 Z-0.0787 R5.7617
G02 X5.9054 Y-18.2165 Z-0.0787 R19.5415
G02 X1.8352 Y-17.7879 Z-0.0787 R19.5415
G02 X-1.0066 Y-16.2587 Z-0.0787 R5.7618
G02 X-1.0751 Y-16.1879 Z-0.0787 R2
G03 X-2.1946 Y-15.6968 Z-0.0787 R1.5217
G01 X-9.4488
G02 X-11.4409 Y-15.5835 Z-0.0787 R17.5728
G02 X-14.4064 Y-12.5498 Z-0.0787 R3.3602
G02 X-14.62 Y-7.8484 Z-0.0787 R51.8248
G02 X-12.62 Y-5.8484 Z-0.0787 R2
G40

Comment: It's not clear how that `TranslateTransform` Matrix is calculated. Since you scale based on the Canvas (your Graphics object's DC), with a scale factor = `float scale = 0.9f;`, the translation `(X1->X2s, Y1->Y2s)` is (without simplifications): `var tx = -(((canvas.Width * scale) - canvas.Width) / 2.0f); var ty = -(((canvas.Height * scale) - canvas.Height) / 2.0f);`. The matrix order is correct (first translate, then scale), but it appears you haven't calculated the translation at all. Note that you can apply the Matrix to the Graphics object: `g.Transform = [Matrix]`.

Comment: You should post the complete code that can reproduce the issue, which includes the other transformations you have there and a sample of the data points (the polygons, or the polygon you want to *contour*) you're drawing. + You also have the `GraphicsPath.Widen()` method (it uses the same Matrix, but adds a `flatness` parameter that may be interesting).

Comment: Ok I’ve updated the code to reflect what I am basing my shape off of

Comment: It is a called "tool radius compensation", CNC machines have this built-in as a feature (G41 and G42).  It is not a linear transform, so Graphics methods can't do it.  Get ahead by googling "tool radius compensation mathematics" and a chat with the boss to tell them it isn't going to be done for a while.

Comment: I know what that is, I have built parametric programs based on that.  This is a question of making the outer layer of the  drawing bigger.  not compensating to make the path bigger.

Comment: To make graphics simply larger use  `ScaleTransform` ! - But this will not really help, in fact it will move things apart unless they are concentric. There is no geometric solution and a practical one will have to use deep knowledge about the goal.